# Can't test protected methods in android (Android studio)

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-studio, protected

I have a project in Android Studio with the main package name com.game.android 
Inside this package I have a class GameMainActivity and another package (named "com.game.android.tests")  where my tests belong. Inside the test package I have GameMainActivityTest which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 . I would like to test the protected methods in the GameMainActivity class and am having trouble seeing the methods.

As far as I know this is how I'm supposed to set up my testing within and Android environment but I guess I could have messed up somewhere. Am new to testing in Android so I'm rather clueless at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a java thing about scope.  Your test classes are setup just fine, but the "protected" modified makes these methods inaccessible from classes not belonging "come.game.andriod".

If you want to test the code in these methods directly, you'll need to either make them public, or create new methods that wrap or call your protected methods somehow.  You could also subclass your original classes in test.

Comment: This is incorrect. `protected` makes them available to subclasses. If you don't supply a scope specifier, that's "package protected", which makes them available to anything else in the same package. It's fairly common practice to make methods available for testing that are package protected, and to ensure the test classes are in the same package.

Comment: True, I didn't accurately describe "protected".  I guess was I simply trying to relay the fact that his issue is that the methods are inaccessible from outside of that package.

Comment: That's the problem. Thing is I can't run tests from elsewhere. This is the recommended set up and it doesn't work unless I only test public methods (which is silly).